# How can i create cookies in asp.net without setting expiry time?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create cookie without setting expiry time.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) :

> For a cookie to effectively never expire, you can set the expiration
>   date to be 50 years from now.

Be careful that if you create a cookie without an expiry time:

> If you do not set the cookie's expiration, the cookie is created but
>   it is not stored on the user's hard disk. Instead, the cookie is
>   maintained as part of the user's session information. When the user
>   closes the browser, the cookie is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Set the expiration date to far future, like 2020